# Getting POST parameters with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to get the parameter inside a post request in Spring. I have used both the annotation (@RequestParam) and also the getParam method, but none of them work for me. Same code is able to get the parameters when I send them by URL (?input=input). Can anyone help me with this? Here is my code that handles the request:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/this",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String receiver(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam(value="input") String input, Model model){
    String input2 = request.getParameter("input");
    model.addAttribute("input",input);
    return "test";
}
```

Right now the code uses the annotation to take the input. If I change the model.attribute("input",input) to model.attribute("input",input2) then I would be using the get attribute method. Both work fine when I pass the parameter with the URL but when I pass the parameter using POST form none of them work. 
And here is the view. it just prints the input parameter from the model:

```
<!DOCTYPE http>
<html>
<body>
test
${input}

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is the code executed, just without the POSTed value?  What's the code doing the POST?

Comment: Yes when I send the input parameter with post method, I get the page without anything for the input parameter (NULL i guess)

Comment: How are you making your post call? Where's your post call code? Is it an ajax call?

Comment: @SurajBajaj Yes the problem was the post request's types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my answer. I did not know about different types of POST requests. All I needed to do was to enable multipartResolver to be able to get "multipart/form-data". I was not aware that the Request mapping by default does not take POST of type "multipart/form-data". If you want to use multipartResolver [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch16s08.html) is the documentation.